# Method not executed using Magento observer

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

I'm trying to set up an event observer in Magento. The event I'm am observing IS fired but it would seem that my method won't run. My module is registered and all is fine.

Here's the config.xml that defines the observers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <technoberglink>
                <class>
                    Technoberg_Link_Model
                </class>
            </technoberglink>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <cms_page_render><!-- sales order place after -->
                <observers>
                    <Technoberg_Link_Observer>
                        <type>
                            singleton
                        </type>
                        <class>
                            Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer
                        </class>
                        <method>
                            start_link
                        </method>
                    </Technoberg_Link_Observer>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_render>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now I do know that the event is fired because if I change the class of Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer to something else a few errors are logged stating that the file couldn't be found.

Here's my Observer.php file

```
class Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer {

function __construct(){

}


public function start_link($e){

    Mage::log("Dummy code executed");
    return $this;

}
}
```

I have no idea why my method isn't executed so any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it. **I checked for all the whitespaces that wasn't the problem.**

***I put the events under global and changed the tag inside the observer to the same name as the class I'm using***. That fixed the problem. So XML would be

```
    <global>
      <events>
        <cms_page_render>
            <observers>
                <Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer> <!-- TAG INSIDE OBSERVER -->
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>start_link</method>
                </Technoberg_Link_Observer>
            </observers>
        </cms_page_render>
      </events>
    </global>
```

I guess Magento is just really strict when it comes to their naming conventions =) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<events>
            <cms_page_render><!-- sales order place after -->
                <observers>
                    <Technoberg_Link_Observer>
                        <type>
                            singleton
                        </type>
                        <class>
                            Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer
                        </class>
                        <method>
                            start_link
                        </method>
                    </Technoberg_Link_Observer>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_render>
        </events>
```

write this part of the xml within

```
<global> </global>
```

tag not the frontend tag

clear cache and reload

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config.xml... I think it is a whitespace problem...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <technoberglink>
                <class>Technoberg_Link_Model</class>
            </technoberglink>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <cms_page_render>
                <observers>
                    <technoberglink>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Technoberg_Link_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>start_link</method>
                    </technoberglink>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_render>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Yes, remove whitespace from your text values in config.